# A way around creating a std::string that stores different types

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I have a function that takes in a `void*` which is then casted to `uint8*` and then populated. In the caller code, it's then appended to `std::string`. Sort of like in the example below.

But I want to make it generic such that I could store different types into string without hardcoding for specific type in the caller code. For e.g: if I were to store `0x5` in a char array, I'd have to use `to_string()` as shown below. However if I have to store a `char` itself, I wouldn't have to use `to_string()`.

```
void foo(void *p) {
    uint8_t *ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p);  
    *ptr = 0x5; // for e.g 

    // now ptr stores a char. th
    *ptr = 'C'; 
}
int main(void) {
   char arr[20] = {0};
   std::string str;
   foo(arr);
   for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
      str += to_string(arr[i]);
   }
   cout << str; // 
}
```

Here's a sample code: https://cplayground.com/?p=jackal-cormorant-koala

you can see how it doesn't print when an integer is stored mainly cause I didn't use `to_string()`. I'm just looking to have a generic function that stores the value as it is. If `15` is stored in a char array, string stores `"15"`. If `'A'` is stored in a char array, string stores `"A"`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217050/discussion-on-question-by-xyf-a-way-around-creating-a-stdstring-that-stores-di).

Answer (score 0):

Although comments about serialization are the way to go, if you only want to create a `string` with `char` and `int` you can overload a function.

```
std::string store(int n) {
    return std::to_string(n); 
}

std::string store(char c) {
    std::string s;
    s += c;
    return std::string(s); 
}

int main(void) {
    //char arr[5] = {0};

    std::string str = store(15);
    cout << "String: " << str << endl;

    // ----------------------------------
    str += store('A');
    cout << "String: " << str << endl;
    //populateString(arr);
   
}
```

Output:

```
String: 15
String: 15A
```

Comment: right, but in my code I have a `char array` that stores the values and gets appended to `std::string`. so anything stored in a char array would always call the function with `char` as an argument type